# How to store input to a list?

Tags: python, list

```
userinput = input("Enter your name: ")
names = []
```

My question is, how to store the input to the list?
I tried to add it like a integer, but it doesn't work.

Comment: So what is the problem, add to list or convert to int ?

Answer (score 2):

since names is a list, you want to append the input to it.

```
userinput = input("Enter your name: ")
names = []
names.append(userinput)
print(names)
```

Answer (score 1):

`names.append(userinput)` you this code and should work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put all answers to a list, you can use append() function.

```
userinput = input("Enter your name: ")
names = []

names.append(userinput)
```

Answer (score 0):

`int(userinput)` makes it an int and `[]` makes it a seperate list so you can append it instead of adding it.

```py
userinput = input("Enter your name: ")
names = []

names += [int(userinput)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 =["Jack","Donald"]

newname = input("Enter new name: ")

list1.append(newname)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the append method. Example:

```
    names = []
    while True:
        name = input("Enter a name or <enter> if you are finished: ")
        if name == '':
            break
        else:
            names.append(name)
    print(f'You entered {names}')
```